# Can't seem to find a particular question/answer, what do i do?

Tags: discussion

I have been trying to locate a particular answer but couldn't find it, even when using every bit of information I remember from the answer in question (in my case: it was an answer about dealing with the impostor syndrome and contained lots of links, if I remember correctly written by F'x)

I figured that could be a good meta question; what can you do if you cant find some material on AC.SE even though you are sure it exists (or -ed at some point)?

Comment: Ask others for their help, on the chat or here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not by me: the only post I ever wrote on the issue is [that one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/11768/2700), and though it contains a few links it's very short.

I can also confirmed that there is no such post among our deleted answers, unless it doesn't actually contain the word “impost[oe]r” (and even then, chances that good content was deleted are very slim).

Maybe you didn't find it on account of the two possible spellings? (-or/-er)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/11765/ive-somehow-convinced-everyone-that-im-actually-good-at-this-how-to-effect/11774#11774) is the question you're looking for, anyway. Not sure why it wouldn't show up in a search. If you know that someone posted an answer to a specific question, I definitely recommend searching their "answers" page ([e.g., my own](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/73/eykanal?tab=answers)). That's how I found this particular question.

Comment: well it apparently didnt show up in my `impostor syndrome is:question` search because the OP (or I) misspelled it :) anyways thanks for the link to the question

Comment: Both variants (imposter/impostor) are accepted spellings. Also: you misspelt “misspelled” ;-)